# The Book of Why, Chapter 3, argument on objectivity of P(L), where L is the length of a billiard table

Tags: bayesian, causality

I am reading the Book of Why by J. Pearl and D.Mackenzie and I cannot understand one of their comments. Page 108 says:

> Bayes assumed that L is determined mechanically by shooting a billiard ball from a greater distance, say, L*. In this way he bestowed objectivity onto P(L)"

I don't understand

- What does it mean to be "determined mechanically"?
- What distance is being compared to L*. I understand there is some distance X such that L* is greater than X. What is X?
- How does this assumption help to show the objectivity of P(L)?

I attempted to find where Bayes talks about this assumption in the 1763 essay but couldn't. Any ideas?

Comment: "Determined mechanically" means by shooting the ball.  The distance $L^{*}$ is being compared to the only other distance in the quotation, $L$ itself.  That leaves us only your third bullet, but what do you mean by "objectivity" and "$P(L)$"??

Comment: Objectivity is not the term I invented. The book next sentence is "In this way he bestowed objectivity onto P(L)". I added it to the question. Also, in their own words on page 89, objectivity means "reasoning exclusively from data and experiment".

Comment: Doesn't that directly answer your third question?  The first two refer to experiments.  An account of Bayes' experiment, including extensive quotations and a reproduction of a key figure, appears in Stephen Stigler's *The History of Statistics.* Stigler references "from Bayes, 1764, p. 385."